# Unable to send a message to myself on phone using the Bots for Messenger API -getting 400 response from messenger API?

Tags: bots, facebook-messenger

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token= <"PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN">

JSON to be POST with API like

```
{
    "recipient": {
        "phone_number": "phone_number"
    },
    "message": {
        "text": "text_msg"
    }
}
```

But when I use sender Id in place of phone number it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Did You add the permission `pages_messaging_phone_number` on your Facebook App?

Here the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/entry-points#phone_numbers[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/entry-points#phone_numbers)

Answer (score 0):

There are few requirements -

- You will have to activate the customer matching on your page. It requires you to   pay $99 one time cost.
- Activate `pages_messaging_phone_number` on your Facebook App, This requires approval from FB.
- Either the page has US address or one of the admin is has US address 
  in his/her FB account.
- The phone number can be in any country. Its a string with country
  code. e.g. for India - "+919999999". 
  You can send name for better accuracy also.

Here is the reference - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

Answer (score 0):

I made a tool just for that !

https://www.nimrod-messenger.io/

Instead of using the Facebook API directly, you just have to make a POST request with your API key and your message.